# UICollectionViewFlowLayout with horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I really want to understand what is preventing my collection view to be  horizontal?

The code is from online tutorial for expanding Cells when scrolling.

- I have set the layout to custom
- Have set the class to MyClassFlowLayout in Storyboard
- Have set scrollDirection = .horizontal in prepare() method

But the collection view is still vertical.

```
struct MyLayoutConstants {
  struct Cell {
    // The height of the non-featured cell
    static let standardHeight: CGFloat = 50
    // The height of the first visible cell
    static let featuredHeight: CGFloat = 150
  }
}

import UIKit

class MyClassFlowLayout:  UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    // The amount the user needs to scroll before the featured cell changes
    let dragOffset: CGFloat = 80.0
    
    var cache: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
    
    // Returns the item index of the currently featured cell
    var featuredItemIndex: Int {
      // Use max to make sure the featureItemIndex is never < 0
      return max(0, Int(collectionView!.contentOffset.y / dragOffset))
    }
    
    // Returns a value between 0 and 1 that represents how close the next cell is to becoming the featured cell
    var nextItemPercentageOffset: CGFloat {
      return (collectionView!.contentOffset.x / dragOffset) - CGFloat(featuredItemIndex)
    }
    
    // Returns the width of the collection view
    var width: CGFloat {
      return collectionView!.bounds.width
    }
    
    // Returns the height of the collection view
    var height: CGFloat {
      return collectionView!.bounds.height
    }
    
    // Returns the number of items in the collection view
    var numberOfItems: Int {
      return collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
    }
    
    
  
    
    

}




extension MyClassFlowLayout {
    // Return the size of all the content in the collection view
    override var collectionViewContentSize : CGSize {
      let contentHeight = (CGFloat(numberOfItems) * dragOffset) + (height - dragOffset)
      return CGSize(width: width, height: contentHeight)
    }
    
    
    override func prepare() {
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
      scrollDirection = .horizontal
 //----------------------------------------------------------------       
      cache.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        
      let standardHeight = MyLayoutConstants.Cell.standardHeight
      let featuredHeight = MyLayoutConstants.Cell.featuredHeight
    
      var frame = CGRect.zero
      var y: CGFloat = 0
      
      for item in 0..<numberOfItems {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        // Important because each cell has to slide over the top of the previous one
        attributes.zIndex = item
        // Initially set the height of the cell to the standard height
        var height = standardHeight
        if indexPath.item == featuredItemIndex {
          // The featured cell
          let yOffset = standardHeight * nextItemPercentageOffset
          y = collectionView!.contentOffset.y - yOffset
          height = featuredHeight
        } else if indexPath.item == (featuredItemIndex + 1) && indexPath.item != numberOfItems {
          // The cell directly below the featured cell, which grows as the user scrolls
          let maxY = y + standardHeight
          height = standardHeight + max((featuredHeight - standardHeight) * nextItemPercentageOffset, 0)
          y = maxY - height
        }
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        attributes.frame = frame
        cache.append(attributes)
        y = frame.maxY
      }

    }

    
    
    
    // Return all attributes in the cache whose frame intersects with the rect passed to the method
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
      var layoutAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
      for attributes in cache {
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
          layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
      }

      return layoutAttributes
    }
    
    
    
    // Return the content offset of the nearest cell which achieves the nice snapping effect, similar to a paged UIScrollView
    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
      let itemIndex = round(proposedContentOffset.y / dragOffset)
      let yOffset = itemIndex * dragOffset
        scrollDirection = .horizontal
      return CGPoint(x: 0, y: yOffset)
    }
    
    // Return true so that the layout is continuously invalidated as the user scrolls
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
      return true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you changed the scroll direction to `Vertical` in storyboard in attributes Inspector?

Comment: I'm not using flow anymore in storyboard I'm using custom class, when you switch to Custom there won't be that option anymore, that's why I have change it on the code in  prepare() method `scrollDirection = .horizontal`